# Splitting lines from a file adds \t instead of white space

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a txt file which contains cookies that i need to split every new line . Problem is i keep getting escaped tab characters instead of whitespaces.

This is the text file :

```
.xxxxxx.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1564915174  did Vd08VIDr01SphvJn
.xxxxxx.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1564915174  didts   1533379178
```

this is my code :

```
list = open('GoogleChrome_Default.txt','r').read().split('\n')
print(list)
```

and this is the output :

```
['.xxxxxx.com\tTRUE\t/\tFALSE\t1564915174\tdid\tVd08VIDr01SphvJn', '.xxxxxx.com\tTRUE\t/\tFALSE\t1564915174\tdidts\t1533379178']
```

I also tried using .readlines() and loop through the file while appending each line to the list but i got the same results .

if i try the same code on this txt file which contains tabs too :

```
Hello    World
Foo    Bar
```

i get my desired output without any escaped characters :

```
['Hello    World', 'Foo    Bar']
```

So , how do i prevent those escaped characters showing up when splitting a text file ? and why those characters appear at all ?
Thanks !

Comment: Your original files contains tabs; when you print a list of strings print will display the string representation of the list, hence the '\t'

Comment: Why do you want to do this anyway? If you write the output as string (not list of strings) it will be as you desire

Comment: @Chris_Rands - Silly me didn't took in consideration it reads tabs as \t same as \n . I have a big file of cookies which i wanted to sort but actually saving it as a string straight to the file will also work ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this after reading in your list

```
list = [item.replace('\t','   ') for item in list]
```

to replicate the other output

the reason your second file does not act the same way is because some text editors will input four spaces (`4*' '`) when you hit tab instead of an actual tab character which is `'\t'`

Comment: they don't wan to get rid of them, they want to view the tabs as whitespace rather than the `repr()` of the tab

Comment: ah, i misunderstood, fixed my response

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your second sample, the text editor has already converted your `\t` tab character into spaces.

Open the text file in your text editor you used to save.  When you move through the supposed "tab" character, you'll notice the cursor is actually moving through 4 separate spaces instead of one tab character.

If you write the following into a text file:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('hello\tworld\n')
    file.write('foo\t\tbar')
```

You'll notice it looks the same in your text editor when opened, but when you move through the `\t` now the cursor only moves once through 4 spaces.  Now write a new line in your text editor with a tab and save.

When you read it back:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    data.split('\n')
```

You'll see the exact same result for the first two lines but different for the last:

```
# ['hello\tworld', 'foo\t\tbar', 'test    hello']
```